# Charging a lithium-ion battery using a lead-acid battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lead-acid

I want to charge a lithium-ion battery using a lead-acid battery, but I want the two batteries to be isolated from each other. Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit: Both the batteries are rated for 12 Volts and the charging current can go upto 20Amps

Comment: Use a transformer-based converter. Your question will need more detail of your requirements before you get any more detail in the answers.

Comment: 12V car charger -> 5V USB port -> any USB-5V powered Li-Ion battery charging circuit (this last one is complex so just buy a charger circuit for Li-ion battery)

Comment: Using an *isolated DC-DC converter* between the lead-acid battery and the Li-ion battery charger seems a good way forward. You can google what's in italics to learn more. If you want more detail, please add your specific requirements to your question.

Comment: What voltage?  For each battery.

Comment: @ocrdu I looked into a DC-DC converter, I do have one at my disposal, but I need to control the current. which I am not able to do with the one that I have despite it having a potentiometer dedicated to control the current. Maybe it is just the fault of the specific converter that I have.

Comment: @Whatsinaname: you will need a proper charger to take care of that behind the DC/DC converter. The DC/DC converter is not a charger and should not be used as a Li-ion charger. Another way to go is using a wireless charger set-up (e.g. as used in phones) as described in Andy aka's answer.

Comment: Is this a one-off or mass production? If one-off, how about a 12 V to 120/230 VAC inverter followed by a 3/4S 20 A lithium-ion charger?

Comment: Thanks @ocrdu, I will look into it.

Comment: @winny, this will be under mass production and hence the indecision from my side.

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to charge a lithium-ion battery using a lead-acid battery, but
> I want the two batteries to be isolated from each other. Is there any
> way to achieve this?*

You can use a Qi-compliant wireless charger like this: -

[image]

[Figure 4:  A Qi-compliant wireless power system, with Panasonic's AN32258A and the NN32251A](https://www.mouser.co.uk/applications/fuel-wireless-charging/). The article (called Wireless Charging) also shows other options such as this: -

[image]

There's also this non-Qi-compliant circuit from [Wireless Charger Design Principle Concept Explained](http://electronicsbeliever.com/wireless-charger-design-principle-explained/): -

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andy, This could work for me. Will I be able to control the current or will it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Many *isolated DC-DC converters* exist. Use one to power your battery charger.

Such converters are similar but not identical to other switching converters you may be familiar with, such as buck or boost converters, but the coil is replaced by two separate coils, making a transformer. The design may be slightly different to optimize energy transfer through the transformer. Feedback signals are opto-isolated.

You can get one that has the same voltage input and output, or you can get one that changes the voltage - a capability that comes practically for free since there's already a transformer in the middle.

Technically, it should be possible to make an isolated battery charger using the same principles, but it would be a quite niche part and I doubt they are made, so unless you want to make one from scratch, I would stick with an isolated converter feeding a normal battery charger. (Google tells me you can buy an isolated 12V lead-acid charger that is sometimes useful in some automotive applications like towing)

Comment: I wouldn't say they are *similar to* switching converters; they're a *type of* switching converter.